# Django: collectstatic command freezes

Tags: django

Using `django-storages==1.4` with django 1.9.2

while running `python manage.py collectstatic` hangs[image]

after typing yes and [Enter], it just hangs. Nothing seems to be copied and the command never finishes.
Has any one faced the issue ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj  even y not working.

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a solution?

Comment: sorry, don't remember solution now. @SabrinaLeggett

Comment: I ended up running again and it worked